# Saving information for connection (jdbc)

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm going to connect to database. My information for connection contains in the .xml file. Where should I keep this information? (in a class, in a interface, or once to use and forget).

Comment: If you want to connect to the db again, u should!

Comment: @facundofarias not that easily. It will be better to use a database connection pool rather than naively opening connections.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza of course!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a best practice the database information should be kept externally to the application as the database might change or you might be changing environments.

In case you need to change the database information, this approach will allow you to have your code untouched and only update the external file.

Comment: Well, there are two basic ways to read database config. information: .xml and .properties files. I'm going to choose file with properties. I wanting to know, as and where I can save this information. For example, in a class or in a interface. What is better fit to situation?

Comment: You will need to configure your database connection manager or datasource in a class. This class will pull all database configurations externally (i.e. via properties file).  You can use interfaces to store constants, although Interfaces are intended for a different purpose, therefore I woudn't recommend it.

Comment: public class Data {
    private static Properties properties;
    
    static {
       properties = new Properties();
        //here I read file with properties and write to static variable
        }
    }
//further, I write getters for all properties, for example:
    public static String getUser() {
        return properties.getProperty("db.user");
    }

it's good solution?

Comment: It is a good solution. Note that you do not need to write getters for all properties, you can have one method like public static String getProperty(String property){ return properties.getProperty(property);} . Then you can get the db user propery like data.getProperty("db.user");